# How can I hook a new 17" MacBook Pro up to a 30" monitor?

Tags: display, macbook, adapter

Suppose I purchase [a brand-new, top of the line, 17" MacBook Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC226LL/A?mco=Nzk2MDg2OA):

[image]

What do I need to do in order to connect it to a 30" monitor?

I already own 2 30" monitors ([a Dell 3007WFP and a Dell 3008WFP](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/category.aspx?c=us&category_id=4009&cs=19&l=en&nf=177~0~174493,4723~0~382981&s=dhs&~ck=anav&navla=4723~0~382981)), so ideally I would hook the MBP up to one of those. However, if it came down to it, I might be willing to buy a new monitor.

Two thoughts:

1. [Will this adapter work? (For the 3008WFP)](http://estore.circuitassembly.com/products/Mini-Displayport-to-Displayport-Adapter-Cable.html)
2. Will [Apples's Mini DisplayPort -> Dual-Link DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A) work?

**Note:** I'm not interested in any solution that requires me to use the 30" monitor at less than its maximum resolution (2560 by 1600 pixels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just purchased a [Dell U3011](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&sku=224-9949) monitor. Amongst its inputs, it has dual-DVI and displayport inputs. I heard bad things about Apple's [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A) adapter so instead went with a [Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6007&seq=1&format=2) cable from Monoprice. Much cheaper and it works perfectly, happily driving 2560 x 1600 from my 15" MacBook Pro (2011 edition). The cable should work fine on any monitor that supports DisplayPort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes all of the new MacBook Pros with a mini-diplayport connector support 2550x1600.

Just look on Apple's website: http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html (Specifically the 'Graphics and video support' section)

To answer the second part: They should both work if used with the proper monitor.

Comment: But what 30" monitor has a Mini DisplayPort input?

Comment: the 3008 seems to have a full-size DisplayPort port
the 3007 seems to have a Dual-Link DVI port